# Google Drive Web Services API for Android - Displaying File Names In A Folder

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive Web Services API for an Android app I'm making.  Right now, I'm trying to obtain a list of filenames in the root folder.  However, I believe my current method for doing this is inefficient:

```
public void searchRoot()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Children.List request = service.children().list("root");
                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ChildList children = request.execute();

                        for(ChildReference child : children.getItems())
                        {
                            File file = service.files().get(child.getId()).execute();
                        }
                        request.setPageToken(children.getNextPageToken());
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        request.setPageToken(null);
                    }
                }
                while(request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {

            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

I think this method is inefficient because I first call request.execute() to get a list of all the children in the root folder, but then I have to call service.files().get(child.getId()).execute() on each and every child, in order to obtain a human-readable filename for each child.  If there's a large number of files in the root folder, this can take an arbitrarily large amount of time to get all the filenames.  My question is -- is there a better way for obtaining the list of filenames?  Like a query that can return all of the filenames in the root folder with just one API call?

As an aside, I understand the Google Drive SDK has the functionality that I'm requesting.  However, I choose to use the Google Drive Web Services API because I'm ultimately trying to stream non-public media from my Google Drive account, and I don't believe the Drive SDK has support for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Instead of using service.children().list("root"), use service.files().list().setQ("'root' in parents")

```
public void searchRoot()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ("'root' in parents");
                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FileList children = request.execute();

                        for(File child : children.getItems())
                        {
                            Log.d("Debug", child.getTitle());
                        }
                        request.setPageToken(children.getNextPageToken());
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        request.setPageToken(null);
                    }
                }
                while(request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
            }
            catch(UserRecoverableAuthIOException e)
            {
                startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_SEARCH_ROOT);
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {

            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```